# How can a Python generator be set running in the background, appending its results to a list as it generates them?

Tags: python, generator, telegram, coroutine

I have a program that receives Telegram messages (using the module [pytg](https://github.com/luckydonald/pytg)). I want its generator function, which receives the messages, to run in the background and simply append any messages it receives to a list. The idea is that the program can be doing its own thing and isn't halted by waiting for messages. It just checks the list of received messages whenever it feels it is appropriate to do so.

So, how can this generator be set running in the background such that it doesn't halt the program to wait for messages?

```
import pytg
import pytg.utils
import pytg.receiver

messages_received = []

@pytg.utils.coroutine
def receiver_function(tg_receiver):
    while True:
        message = (yield)
        messages_received.append(message)
        print("message received and added to list of messages received")

tg_receiver = pytg.receiver.Receiver()
tg_receiver.start()
tg_receiver.message(receiver_function(tg_receiver))
receiver.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for python's [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module. You can spawn some worker threads to run in the background and listen for telegram messages. You should create a thread manager to create workers, and maybe pass a reference to the message list to the workers. This can get tricky though since it seems like you need a shared object between threads.